# uksort() array order is not preserved when there are more than 16 items

Tags: php

I'm experiencing some incredibly weird behaviour with PHP 7.4 and `uksort()`.

Passing an array with more than 16 items to `uksort()` results in loss of the original order:

```
$sixteenItemArray = ['a' => 'A', 'b' => 'B', 'c' => 'C', 'd' => 'D', 'e' => 'E', 'f' => 'F', 'g' => 'G', 'h' => 'H', 'i' => 'I', 'j' => 'J', 'k' => 'K', 'l' => 'L', 'm' => 'M', 'n' => 'N', 'o' => 'O', 'p' => 'P'];

$seventeenItemArray = ['a' => 'A', 'b' => 'B', 'c' => 'C', 'd' => 'D', 'e' => 'E', 'f' => 'F', 'g' => 'G', 'h' => 'H', 'i' => 'I', 'j' => 'J', 'k' => 'K', 'l' => 'L', 'm' => 'M', 'n' => 'N', 'o' => 'O', 'p' => 'P', 'q' => 'Q'];

echo 'Order that a 16 item array is passed to the uksort() callback: ';
uksort($sixteenItemArray, function ($a, $b) {
    echo $a;
});

echo '<br />';

echo 'Order that a 17 item array is passed to the uksort() callback: ';
uksort($seventeenItemArray, function ($a, $b) {
    echo $a;
});
```

That results in:

```
Order that a 16 item array is passed to the uksort() callback: abcdefghijklmno
Order that a 17 item array is passed to the uksort() callback: aiipioinimilikijbhgfedcajponml
```

For context, I am using `uksort()` in a way that relies on the original array order being preserved, it's not a simple sort unfortunately.

Comment: There is no loss of order. PHP is simply iterating through the array. The callback function should contain the comparison method.

Comment: @Cid so how would I go about sorting an array so that string keys are last (but not ordered) and numeric keys are ordered? The original order needs to be preserved in some way.

Comment: That's a job for the comparison callback function

Comment: @Cid how am I able to retain the order of the string keys if the original order is lost...

Comment: That is very interesting! I am getting the same results with PHP 7.2. My suggestion would be to split the array into those that need sorting and those that don't, then sort the array that needs it and finally combine back into a single array. Otherwise, if you could supply us a more realistic example and the sort requirements then I could perhaps come up with some other way.

Comment: @Mark that's exactly what I ended up doing, but obviously, the uksort() version is more performant :( I should probably report this bug to PHP themselves.

Comment: There is no bug. You just don't have put any comparison in the function callback. [Read the documentation !](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php)

Comment: @Cid I realise that, the code I posted simply demonstrates that the sorting algorithm changes when the array reaches 17 items long, thus breaking the sort order. I have since solved this issue using another methods but it's not as performant.